# Using ing form after "to"

Tags: progressive-aspect

I don't understand why second **being** is progressive.

> He went from being a poor student to **being** an outstanding one.

Comment: Can you explain the grammar rule that you think makes the second "being" wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing the preposition "to" used here with the difference between gerunds (verb plus "-ing") and infinitives (to + verb).

sentence with a gerund: I enjoy *swimming*. (Gerunds do not use "to".)

sentence with an infinitive: I want *to swim*.

In your sentence, "to being" does not act as a gerund or an infinitive. The preposition "to" connects the first idea (that the student was poor) to the second (that the student became an outstanding one).

Answer (score 1):

Because “it” here in this context doesn’t act like the same you are considering in your mind.

This kind of “to” isn’t infinitive (to + verb1)

Here “it” illustrates moving from place to place (from condition to another) (from being a poor student to being an outstanding one)

This  [Link](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-use-preposition-to-1211798) explains that there are a few cases where you use to + V + -ing:

> 1) If the to is part of a phrasal verb or verb + preposition combination:
>   A phrasal verb is something like "look forward to", "confess to", etc. In this case, the "to" is part of the verb itself. Some examples are:

- I am looking forward to attending the party
- I am committed to supporting the Linguistics proposal on Area51

> 2) If the to is part of an adjective + preposition combination:
>   For example:

- A lot of women aren’t accustomed to being treated so well!
- I am opposed to increasing taxes.
  These look similar to the examples above, but you can tell that a word like accustomed is an adjective in this case because there is a form of the verb to be. That is, you are an adjective.

> 3) If the to is part of a noun + preposition combination:
>   For example:

- His addiction to gambling has caused a lot of stress for his family.
- Her great dedication to teaching inspires her students.

Comment: I know the phrasal verb part, but your example 2 is difficult for me.  
Can I consider  "accustomed to", "opposed to "  as a  phrase verb so I need to add gerund after "to" ?

Comment: If I change the sentence to "I opposed to increase taxes", Is this correct?

Comment: No, they’re not. “Accustomed , opposed ” are adjectives that go with **certain preposition**  look into the following link and you would realize which adjective goes goes with which preposition; https://www.google.jo/search?client=safari&channel=iphone_bm&dcr=0&ei=ZLNYWv-oD4P4wAK6ubboCQ&q=adjectives+%2B+prepositions+&oq=adjectives+%2B+prepositions+&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0j0i22i30k1l4.2578.28640.0.29312.49.15.23.11.11.0.260.2716.0j11j4.15.28644....0...1c.1j5.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.49.4129.3..41j0i67k1j0i131k1.0.4ZG2FbqYFDo

Comment: thank you, Is the sentence  "I oppose to increase taxes" correct?